# why occur one desfase between JSF action calls?

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, liferay, portlet

I'm working in a portlet application for Liferay 6.2, using primefaces 3.5, it's kind of a documents explorer. The documents are display in the datagrig and every element is a link to open the content in new browsers tab.

My current code works but has a very big bug. First clic doesn't open the document, open a html fragment of portlet in new tab, second time open the previous. To be more clear:

- step 1: clic in document A = open html
- step 2: clic in document B = open document A
- step 3: clic in document C = open document B
- and so on...

I think its not and order of execution problem because log prints correct information of selected document since the first clic

This is view.xhtml fragment

```
<h:form>
    <p:dataGrid var="document" value="#{documentBean.documents}" columns="5" rows="15">
        <p:column>
            <h:commandLink action="#{documentBean.openDocument}" target="_blank">
                <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{documentBean.selectedDocument}" value="#{document}" />
                <p:fileDownload value="#{documentBean.content}" contentDisposition="inline" />
                <h:outputText value="Open Document" />
            </h:commandLink>
        </p:column>
    </p:dataGrid>
</h:form>
```

And this is the most relevant part of mange bean

```
@ManagedBean(name = "documentBean")
@ViewScoped
public class DocumentBean {

private List<DocumentVO> documents;
private DocumentVO selectedDocument;
private StreamedContent content;

@EJB
private DocumentServiceIntegrator documentIntegrator;
private static final Log LOG = LogFactory.getLog(DocumentBean.class);

@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    documents = documentIntegrator.getFolderContentByPath("/");
    selectedDocument = new DocumentVO();
}

public String openDocument() {
    LOG.info("Open document: " + selectedDocument.getId() + " (" + selectedDocument.getName() + ", " + selectedDocument.getMimeType() + ")");
    byte[] bytes = documentIntegrator.getDocumentContentById(selectedDocument.getId());
    LOG.info("Document content: " + (bytes != null ? bytes.length + " bytes" : "null"));
    InputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes);
    content = new DefaultStreamedContent(stream, selectedDocument.getMimeType(), selectedDocument.getName());
    return null;
}

// getters and setters for: documents, selectedDocument and content

}
```

Any ideas of what's happening and how to solve it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround, In view.xhtml I removed the *action* attribute of *h:commandLink* and add a *f:actionListener* tag after the *f:setPropertyActionListener* (order matters)

```
<h:commandLink target="_blank">
    <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{documentBean.selectedDocument}" value="#{document}" />
    <f:actionListener binding="#{documentBean.openDocumentActionListener}" />
    <p:fileDownload value="#{documentBean.content}" contentDisposition="inline" />
    <h:outputText value="Open Document" />
</h:commandLink>
```

In manage bean, I created custom ActionListener with the StreamedContent creation logic

```
@ManagedBean(name = "documentBean")
@ViewScoped
public class DocumentBean {

private List<DocumentVO> documents;
private DocumentVO selectedDocument;
private StreamedContent content;
private ActionListener openDocumentActionListener;

@EJB
private DocumentServiceIntegrator documentIntegrator;
private static final Log LOG = LogFactory.getLog(DocumentBean.class);

@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    documents = documentIntegrator.getFolderContentByPath("/");
    selectedDocument = new DocumentVO();
    openDocumentActionListener = createOpenDocumentActionListener();
}

public ActionListener createOpenDocumentActionListener() {
    ActionListener actionListener = new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void processAction(ActionEvent arg0) throws AbortProcessingException {
            LOG.info("Open document: " + selectedDocument.getId() + " (" + selectedDocument.getName() + ", " + selectedDocument.getMimeType() + ")");
            byte[] bytes = documentIntegrator.getDocumentContentById(selectedDocument.getId());
            LOG.info("Document content: " + (bytes != null ? bytes.length + " bytes" : "null"));
            InputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes);
            content = new DefaultStreamedContent(stream, selectedDocument.getMimeType(), selectedDocument.getName());
        }
    };
    return actionListener;
}

// getters and setters for: documents, selectedDocument, content and openDocumentActionListener

}
```

Something happening outside my knowledge with object content, it seems that it was download in the action before it was already created or prepared.

Hope this help someone, I had no idea on how to google it.